# Mac Visual Studio TFS File must be uploaded before it can be checked In

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-mac, xcasset

I'm trying to check in my xcassets for a Xamarin.Forms project I'm working on. I can't seem to get the files sent to the source control, because on commit I get an error for each image that says

> The contents of the file **$filepath** must be uploaded before it can be checked in.

I know TFS on Mac is young so I was wondering - is this a bug, and if so, is there a workaround? If it's not a bug, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: May be you need to use “add” first and the check in.. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f7e6bf01-2702-40a5-951f-3156952a2692/how-can-we-tell-tfs-to-add-files-added-to-a-project?forum=tfsversioncontrol

Comment: @numbtongue they've already been added to source control. That's what is puzzling. The show up in my list of changes to be committed, they just won't commit for some reason.

Comment: May be you can access it via explorer to either verify or upload these files manually https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/30933610-bring-back-windows-explorer-integration-for-tfs201